# Dispatch usage in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

```
function Notification({ flashMessage }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEmpty(flashMessage)) {
      return null;
    }
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(uiActions.dispatchNotification(flashMessage));
  }, [flashMessage]);

....


return <div>....</div>
};
```

`react-dom.development.js:59 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Can dispatch be not be called in a useEffect hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispatch` can be called inside an effect, but `useDispatch` can not. Hooks all need to be called in the body of the component. The fix is to move useDispatch before the effect.

```
function Notification({ flashMessage }) {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEmpty(flashMessage)) {
      return null;
    }
    dispatch(uiActions.dispatchNotification(flashMessage));
  }, [flashMessage]);

  // etc
}
```